# Direct access to Chrome's Extension API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way how to access the Chrome's extension API directly? What I mean is e.g. something like the Developer's Console for JavaScript, or even javascript: in the URL.

I ask because creating an extension sounds like A LOT of additional work, given that I have never created any. (especially once more advanced permissions [Tabs] get involved).

Comment: You can use it on built-in pages like `chrome://settings`

Comment: Wow! Great trick. Thank you very much... :)